# F# record: ref vs mutable field

Tags: data-structures, f#, mutable

While refactoring my F# code, I found a record with a field of type `bool ref`:

```ml
type MyType =
  {
    Enabled : bool ref
    // other, irrelevant fields here
  }
```

I decided to try changing it to a `mutable` field instead

```ml
// Refactored version
type MyType =
  {
    mutable Enabled : bool
    // other fields unchanged
  }
```

Also, I applied all the changes required to make the code compile (i.e. changing `:=` to `<-`, removing `incr` and `decr` functions, etc).

I noticed that after the changes some of the unit tests started to fail.
As the code is pretty large, I can't really see what exactly changed.

Is there a significant difference in implementation of the two that could change the behavior of my program?

Comment: Without knowing what your tests like, there's no telling what could be going on.

Comment: Would be difficult to copy-paste here a few hundreds lines of code. That's why I decided to keep the example simple instead and ask for differences between the two implementations that could give me an idea.

Comment: So at a high level, mutable values in F# are stored on the stack unless they are captured, at which point they are turned into ref cells. Ref cells are objects on the heap. But other than syntactical changes, that's about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the difference not because one is first-value, passed by reference/value or other things. It's because a `ref` is just a container (class) on its own.

The difference is more obvious when you implement a `ref` by yourself. You could do it like this:

```
type Reference<'a> = {
    mutable Value: 'a
}
```

Now look at both definitions.

```
type MyTypeA = {
    mutable Enabled: bool
}

type MyTypeB = {
    Enabled: Reference<bool>
}
```

`MyTypeA` has a `Enabled` field that can be directly changed or with other word is mutable.

On the other-side you have `MyTypeB` that is theoretically immutable but has a Enabled that reference to a mutable class.

The `Enabled` from `MyTypeB` just reference to an object that is mutable like the millions of other classes in .NET. From the above type definitions, you can create objects like these.

```
let t = { MyTypeA.Enabled = true }
let u = { MyTypeB.Enabled = { Value = true }}
```

Creating the types makes it more obvious, that the first is a mutable field, and the second contains an object with a mutable field.

You find the implementation of `ref` in [FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs) it looks like this:

```
    [<DebuggerDisplay("{contents}")>]
    [<StructuralEquality; StructuralComparison>]
    [<CompiledName("FSharpRef`1")>]
    type Ref<'T> = 
        { 
          [<DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)>]
          mutable contents: 'T }
        member x.Value 
            with get() = x.contents
            and  set v = x.contents <- v

    and 'T ref = Ref<'T>
```

The `ref` keyword in F# is just the built-in way to create such a pre-defined mutable Reference object, instead that you create your own type for this. And it has some benefits that it works well whenever you need to pass `byref`, `in` or `out` values in .NET. So you should use `ref`. But you also can use a `mutable` for this. For example, both code examples do the same.

With a reference

```
let parsed =
    let result = ref 0
    match System.Int32.TryParse("1234", result) with
    | true  -> result.Value
    | false -> result.Value
```

With a mutable

```
let parsed =
    let mutable result = 0
    match System.Int32.TryParse("1234", &result) with
    | true  -> result
    | false -> result
```

In both examples you get a `1234` as an `int` parsed. But the first example will create a `FSharpRef` and pass it to `Int32.TryParse` while the second example creates a field or variable and passes it with `out` to `Int32.TryParse`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a difference. Refs are first-class values, while mutable variables are a language construct.

Or, from a different perspective, you might say that `ref` cells are passed by reference, while mutable variables are passed by value.

Consider this:

```
type T = { mutable x : int }
type U = { y : int ref }

let t = { x = 5 }
let u = { y = ref 5 }

let mutable xx = t.x
xx <- 10
printfn "%d" t.x  // Prints 5

let mutable yy = u.y
yy := 10
printfn "%d" !u.y // Prints 10
```

This happens because `xx` is a completely new mutable variable, unrelated to `t.x`, so that mutating `xx` has no effect on `x`.

But `yy` is a reference to *the exact same ref cell* as `u.y`, so that pushing a new value into that cell while referring to it via `yy` has the same effect as if referring to it via `u.y`.

If you "copy" a `ref`, the copy ends up pointing to the same `ref`, but if you copy a mutable variable, only its value gets copied.

Comment: I see, makes sense. So most likely somewhere in my code I copy the field, modify it and then the change gets discarded in the `mutable` version. Thanks, I'll take a look.